# a group of order $p^3$ contains a normal subgroup of order $p^2$

Tags: group-theory, p-groups

Let $p\neq2$ be a prime number.

Let G be a group s.t. $|G|=p^3$.

**Prove** that there exists $H\triangleleft G$, a normal subgroup of order $p^2$.

Comment: I wonder why you are assuming that $p \ne 2$.

Comment: The way how to prove it depends on what you've learned about groups.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We know there exists a subgroup by Sylow's theorem. It is normal because its index is the smallest prime dividing order of the group.

Comment: But from Sylow we get that there exist a subgroup of order $p^3$, not every power of $p$?

Comment: Every power of p. Subgroup of order $p^3$ is the whole group. It wouldn't help if Sylow said just that.

Comment: That is typically not included as part of Sylow's theorem.

Comment: @daruma  [See theorem 1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sylow_theorems#Proof_of_the_Sylow_theorems)

Comment: Exactly, it's not in the statement of the Sylow's theorem.

Comment: @daruma $G$ has a subgroup of every prime power that divides $|G|$. That is what the theorem states.

Comment: @daruma It follows as a consequence. Sometime Sylow's theorem is stated this way.

Comment: That's like saying Cauchy's theorem is part of Sylow's theorem because you use it in the proof. And that result is not always proved as there are other ways to proof Sylow without invoking that. In any case, it might be worth clarifying because it might cause confusion.

Comment: @daruma If you see page 406 of Contemporary Abstract Algebra by Gallian, the statement of first Sylow theorem is : "Let $G$ be a finite group and $p$ be a prime. If $p^k$ divides $|G|$, then $G$ has at least one subgroup of order $p^k$."

Comment: Whether it is included in the statement of Sylow's theorem obviously depends on the source. Is it important? The way I see it: this answer points to some important results which essentially make a proof of the Q. It probably contains things some readers did not know yet. Except if someone wants to see a very detailed proof, or references for those results (they can be found at Math.SE) I think this answer is perfect.

Answer (score 1):

In fact we can go further: every finite $p$-group $P$ has a  normal subgroup of every possible order (allowed by Lagrange's theorem: so any of $1,p,\cdots,p^n$). There are two key facts that go into proving this: the lattice correspondence theorem, and the fact that any finite $p$-group $P$ has a nontrivial center $Z(P)$.

Indeed, the proof can proceed inductively. Since $Z(P)\le P$ is nontrivial, it has a nontrivial element say $z\in Z(P)$ of order $p$ (which is fairly easy to show for $p$-groups), in which case $P/\langle z\rangle$ has order $p^{n-1}$ and by induction hypothesis has a normal subgroup $\overline{N}\trianglelefteq P/\langle z\rangle$ of prescribed order $p^{k-1}$, which corresponds to a normal subgroup $N\trianglelefteq P$ of order $p^k$.

The lattice correspondence theorem is sometimes called the "Fourth" Isomorphism Theorem, and the fact a finite $p$-group $P$ follows from the [class equation](https://groupprops.subwiki.org/wiki/Class_equation_of_a_group) (which itself follows from the orbit-stabilizer theorem) and basic modular arithmetic.